# Finalizar serviço de outra App

Tags: android, android-service

É o seguinte, eu terei 2 aplicativos rodando no celular de um cliente, um deles apenas inicia alguns serviços e o outro faz algumas operações, o problema é que não posso unificar os dois, é uma longa história, agora gostaria de saber como interromper o serviço da primeira aplicação a partir da segunda, apenas mudando uma variável(EX: servicoAtivo), isso é possivel?

Comment: Gabriel, chegou a verificar se apenas chamando o [`Context.stopService(android.content.Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) passando um `Intent` para o `Service` que deseja parar? Caso esteja dando erro de permissão, você pode tentar colocar as duas aplicações para compartilhar o mesmo usuário e processo e executar o `stopService` normalmente. Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta para ver se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664090/can-multiple-android-applications-share-a-single-process-and-application-context.

Comment: Oi cara valeu, achei a solução, criei uma função na outra app que assim que chamada setava uma variavel que finalizava o serviço, vou postar a solução

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei a solução para o meu problema aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944598/android-change-a-variable-in-service-from-other-app/29944717#29944717

e neste link também: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

Mudando uma variavel para realizar o que era necessario